# keyboard backlight is not working

Tags: hp, backlight

I have just bought a new computer and I installed ubuntu on it but the problem is that I've lost my keyboard backlight   here is my computer

http://store.hp.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/us/en/mdp/Laptops/omen-15--1

from windows i was able to change the color of the lights , now I can't do that any more

excuse my English